# Problemas al Exportar con Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Me encuentro realizando un `export` de una vista, utilizando `laravel excel`. Me estoy guiando con  la documentación del mismo, pero al momento de interactuar con el botón el cual me genera el reporte este no realiza ninguna acción referente al reporte, lo único que hace es enviarme a mi vista `materia.show` la cual en ningún momento hago el llamado en lugar de enviarme a mi vista `materia.export` la cual es la vista que quiero generar el reporte.

Adjunto el codigo pertinente
**MateriaController**

```
public function reporteExcel()
    {

        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'reporteHorario.xlsx');
    }
```

**Clase UsersExport**

```
class UsersExport implements FromView
{
    public function view(): View
    {
    return view('materia.export', [
        'materias' => Materia::all()]);
    }
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('materias/export',[MateriaController::class,'reporteExcel'])->name('materias.export');
```

**Vista `materia.export`**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('template_title')
    Materia
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #063970; color: white;">
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">

                            <span id="card_title">
                                {{ __('Reporte') }}
                            </span>

                            <div class="float-right">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="general" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead class="thead">
                                    <tr>
                                        {{-- <th>No</th> --}}

                                        <th>PGM</th>
                                        <th>FAC</th>
                                        <th>DPTO</th>
                                        <th>SEM</th>
                                        <th>COD</th>
                                        <th>MATERIA</th>
                                        <th>GRUPO</th>
                                        <th>DIA</th>
                                        <th>INICIO</th>
                                        <th>FINAL</th>
                                        <th>AULA</th>
                                        {{-- <th>Tipo de Aula</th> --}}
                                        <th>CUPO</th>
                                        <th>ESTADO</th>
                                        <th>DOC</th>
                                        {{-- <th>Actualizaciones</th> --}}

                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach ($materias as $materia)
                                        <tr>
                                            {{-- <td>{{ ++$i }}</td> --}}

                                            <td>{{ $materia->programa->abreviaturas_programas }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->docente->facultade->abreviaturas_facultades }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->bancomateria->departamento->abreviaturas_departamentos }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->semestre->numero_semestres }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->bancomateria->codigo_materias }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->bancomateria->nombre_materias }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->grupo->codigogrupo->nombre_grupos }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->grupo->horario->dia->nombre_dias }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->grupo->horario->horainicio->hora_inicios }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->grupo->horario->horafinale->hora_finales }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->aula->nombre_aulas }}</td>
                                            {{-- <td>{{ $materia->aula->tipoaula->nombre_tipoaulas }}</td> --}}
                                            <td>{{ $materia->grupo->cupo_grupos }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->grupo->estado_grupos }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $materia->docente->nombre_docentes }}</td>
                                            {{-- <td>{{ $materia->grupo->horario->actualizaciones}}</td> --}}


                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! $materias->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') !!}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Código del `botón`**

```
<a href="{{ route('materias.export') }}" class="btn btn-sm float-right" data-placement=" style="background-color: #cad225; color: white;">
 {{ __('Reporte Excel') }}
</a>
```

Lo que he llegado a analizar es que al momento de interactuar con el botón nunca llega a mi función `reporteExcel` de mi `materiaController`, retorna todo el tiempo a una vista la cual no he referenciado y no genera el `reporte` deseado. Gracias

Comment: revisa en tu archivo web si no tiene repetido la url 'materias/export', suele ser una causa del porque no llega al controller

Answer (score 0):

no se si lo solucionaste, yo tuve el mismo problema.

Debes definir la ruta con punto, así lo solucione

```
Route::get('materias.export',[MateriaController::class,'reporteExcel'])->name('materias.export');
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).